# Wordpress - Display Categories in Hierarchy Order, Not Alphabetically

Tags: wordpress

This is what I am working with:

```
 if ( ! function_exists( 'cb_byline' ) ) {  
    function cb_byline($cb_cat = true, $cb_post_id = NULL, $cb_short_comment_line = false, $cb_posts_on = false) {

    $cb_meta_onoff = ot_get_option('cb_meta_onoff', 'on'); 
    $cb_disqus_code = ot_get_option('cb_disqus_shortname', NULL);
    $cb_byline = $cb_cat_output = $cb_comments = NULL;
    $cb_cats = get_the_category($cb_post_id);

    if ( isset( $cb_cats ) && ( $cb_cat == true ) ) {
        $cb_cat_output = ' <div class="cb-category"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i> ';
        $i = 1;
        foreach($cb_cats as $category) {
            if ( $i != 1 ) { $cb_cat_output .= '-> '; }
             $cb_cat_output .= ' <a href="'.get_category_link( $category->cat_ID  ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>';
             $i++;
        }
        $cb_cat_output .= '</div>';
```

This outputs the categories in alphabetical order.

I need the categories to display from top level -> bottom level.

I am not an expert coder but I have looked around for quite a bit and was unable to find a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the parent categories for each of your categories using

```
get_category_parents( $id, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited );
```

This will return something like "Category » Subcategory » Subsubcategory »"

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents

**edit: Full code**

```
$cb_meta_onoff = ot_get_option('cb_meta_onoff', 'on'); 
$cb_disqus_code = ot_get_option('cb_disqus_shortname', NULL);
$cb_byline = $cb_cat_output = $cb_comments = NULL;
$cb_cats = get_the_category($cb_post_id);

if ( isset( $cb_cats ) && ( $cb_cat == true ) ) {
    $cb_cat_output = ' <div class="cb-category"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i> ';
    $i = 1;
    foreach($cb_cats as $category) {
        if ( $i != 1 ) { $cb_cat_output .= '-> '; }
         $cb_cat_output .= get_category_parents( $category->cat_ID ) . '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->cat_ID  ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", "cubell" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>';
         $i++;
    }
    $cb_cat_output .= '</div>';
```

Comment: I know of this but I'm not entirely sure where I insert it. I've tried substituting it with "get_the_category" but it doesn't work.